# How to find two events

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to combine the following two event listeners into one statement?

```
$('.series input').on('change', do_something);
$('.series input').on('keyup', do_something);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Read the [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/) of the tools you use.

> `.on( events [, selector ] [, data ], handler )`
>
> `events`
>
> *Type*: String
>
> One or more space-separated event types and optional namespaces, such as "click" or "keydown.myPlugin".

So add a space between the events

```
$('.series input').on('change keyup', do_something);
```